# Rearrange items in a Google Keep list

Tags: google-keep

I maintain a master to-do list and a master "topics" list.  Often an older list item becomes more urgent and I want to move it near the top of the list (so I can control which undone items show up in my Android widget)

Is that possible?

Comment: Alternatively, for my use case, any idea if there's a way to add an item to the TOP of the list rather than adding to the bottom and DRAGGING it to the top? If I add 4 items to the top of a long list it ends up taking a couple of minutes to get them all where I want them

Answer (score 3):

There is a small ribbon next to the check box. You can drag and move list entries with that.

[image]

Comment: It makes sense, but the ribbon never worked for me. I tried click-n-drag, press-n-drag, double (click then press and drag), but I can never move the items. I seem able to mark the items as done, I can edit items, etc. but not move them. Is there maybe some lock I have to release or something along these lines?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's difficult to press this control, but this answer works as of the latest update (4.1.131.18.40) 11 Apr 2018.

Comment: Not working in 95% of tries. This should be fixed.

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to add an item to the TOP of the list rather than adding to the bottom and DRAGGING it to the top?  If I add 4 items to the top of a long list it ends up taking a couple of minutes to get them all where I want them

Comment: @BrentBow I do that by hitting return before the first item. Pictures explain better than words... https://youtu.be/cfsrO4L4HpY

Comment: Thank you, @TimoSchwarzer!  So simple and effective

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the drag to work, I had to first click "+ List Item".  This made the ribbons "dragable"for me.

Answer (score 1):

The + doesn't have a "List Item" option. The last update to Google Keep broke the ability to move list items. Workaround: Highlight the list item, cut and paste in new spot.

Answer (score 0):

When using my phone, I finally figured it out after trying just about everything. Make a very slight sweeping/swiping motion over the dots to the left of the item will stick it to your thumb right away so you can drop it elsewhere. Note, your thumb needs to be in the swiping motion before touching the icon... touching the icon and  then sweeping will not work.  Just touch the icon midway during the swiping.  Just do the slightest little sweep or swipe, no clicking or pressing and holding worked for me. Works easily now 100% of the time with this itty bitty sweep on the icon, at least for me. Good luck, hopefully they will improve this.

Answer (score 0):

Sweep the dots to the right first, so it is indented. Then move it up to wherever you want.